# How to keep PS4 controller connected?

Tags: ps4, controllers

When I connect my PS4 controller to Bluetooth, I need to remove and re-pair the controller every single time I disconnect. I have tried pressing the PlayStation button that appears to request connection, but it doesn't say "Connected" in Bluetooth settings. Is there a way around this? Just annoying to need to re-pair it every single time.

Comment: well you could still use the USB cable. what makes the Duelshock Controllers for the PS3/4 better than the XBox ones is that they came with USB cables which can turn them into wired controllers rather than wireless

Comment: well yeah but what if I want to use bluetooth tho. Too bad?

Comment: well you do ask for a way around it than needing to re-pair it all the time. to be honest i think there's a deeper problem here as my 2 controllers both have never needed to be re-paired after being paired once and you say your controller doesn't show up in the list of connections despite actually working which is odd because if i recall the Turn off Devices list when you press the PS Button is the same list in the Bluetooth Settings (though i could be wrong so i'll confirm it myself on the weekend when i get on it)